How to calculate the voltage gain of a circuit with P-MOS and N-MOS transistors?
I was asked to calculate the voltage gain of a circuit containing 2 P-MOS and one N-MOS transistors:

I calculated the operating point and got: gm1 = gm2 = gm3 = 2 [ms]
The circuit that I built for small signal analysis was:

but now I am not sure how to find the relationship between Vin and Vout.
EDIT: Ignore the Rds resistor, it is for another question.

Raed Jayyousi - Hi, Where did that image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More site rules in the [tour] & [help].)

See M2 & M3 form a current mirror -- M3's current is equal to M2. M2's current is equal to M1.
For your (homework ?) answer, be sure to include the polarity (+ or -) of the gain.

There are two inverting stages. Ignoring rds, the gain of each stage is determined by gm times drain load.
The load in the 1st stage is a diode connected PMOS. First stage gain is Av1 = - gm1 * 1/gm2 and 2nd stage gain is Av2 = - gm3 * (RD || RL). Total gain would then be Av = Av1 * Av2.
With gm1 = gm2 = gm3 = gm the overall gain is Av = gm * (RD || RL).
